# Duplicate workflow on the same list sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, 2007, designer-workflow, duplicate

i created a workflow on my custom list that does some actions. I want to duplicate the same workflow. I have to do that because many steps are the same.

My problem is when i copy and past the workflow, i can run only the second one. (the second one hides the first one).

Can i duplicate the workflow and running both?

Thanks,
regards
Francesco

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the SharePoint designer tool, it will allow you to view all the workflows. Then you will be able to easily edit your workflow depend on your need. Some workflows in sharepoint 2007 will not be able to see/edit from the browser.